# Uma das tabelas não está sendo criada - JPA/Hibernate com MySQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou com um problema ao executar minha classe de teste:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import br.com.teste.jpa.c_mapeamento.model.Conta;

public class PopulaConta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManager manager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();

        Conta conta1 = new Conta();
        Conta conta2 = new Conta();
        Conta conta3 = new Conta();

        conta1.setBanco("001 - BANCO DO BRASIL");
        conta1.setNumero("16987-8");
        conta1.setAgencia("6543");
        conta1.setTitular("Maria dos Santos");

        conta2.setBanco("237 - BANCO BRADESCO");
        conta2.setNumero("86759-1");
        conta2.setAgencia("1745");
        conta2.setTitular("Paulo Roberto Souza");

        conta3.setBanco("341 - BANCO ITAU UNIBANCO");
        conta3.setNumero("46346-3");
        conta3.setAgencia("4606");
        conta3.setTitular("Antonio Duraes");

        // persistindo as contas
        manager.persist(conta1);
        manager.persist(conta2);
        manager.persist(conta3);

        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        manager.close();

    }
}
```

A classe acima não tem problemas no código, o problema é que não cria a tabela cliente automaticamente e diz que essa tabela não existe.

Log:

```
ago 30, 2018 9:34:04 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
ago 30, 2018 9:34:04 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final}
ago 30, 2018 9:34:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ago 30, 2018 9:34:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/teste?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {autocommit=true, release_mode=auto, user=root}
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions (file:/G:/workspace_alura/JPA%20Persista%20Objetos/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: teste.categoria
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [nome, id]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: db.cliente
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [nome, id]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: teste.conta
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [numero, banco, id, agencia, titular]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
ago 30, 2018 9:34:05 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: teste.movimentacao
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [tipo, data, conta_id, valor, id, descricao]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk257eb9231c7c520e]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk257eb9231c7c520e, primary]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: teste.movimentacao_categoria
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [categoria_id, movimentacao_id]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fkfc77e4f7724131a6, fkfc77e4f72b7c518e]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fkfc77e4f7724131a6, fkfc77e4f72b7c518e]
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table Cliente add column endereco varchar(255)
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Table 'teste.cliente' doesn't exist
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table Cliente add column profissao varchar(255)
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Table 'teste.cliente' doesn't exist
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table Cliente add column conta_id integer unique
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Table 'teste.cliente' doesn't exist
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table Cliente add index FK96841DDAA1A8D395 (conta_id), add constraint FK96841DDAA1A8D395 foreign key (conta_id) references Conta (id)
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Table 'teste.cliente' doesn't exist
ago 30, 2018 9:34:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

Entidade Cliente

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private String profissao;
    private String endereco;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Conta conta;

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public Cliente(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    // getters e setters    
}
```

Isso ocorre apenas quando uso MySQL. Usando PostgreSQL funciona sem problemas.

Aqui está meu arquivo persintence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="contas-mysql">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>br.com.teste.jpa.c_mapeamento.model.Conta</class>
    <class>br.com.teste.jpa.c_mapeamento.model.Movimentacao</class>
    <class>br.com.teste.jpa.c_mapeamento.model.Categoria</class>
    <class>br.com.teste.jpa.c_mapeamento.model.Cliente</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/teste?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="contas-postgre">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>br.com.teste.jpa.c_mapeamento.model.Conta</class>
    <class>br.com.teste.jpa.c_mapeamento.model.Movimentacao</class>
    <class>br.com.teste.jpa.c_mapeamento.model.Categoria</class>
    <class>br.com.teste.jpa.c_mapeamento.model.Cliente</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/alura" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="ROOT" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: "*Table found: teste.categoria*", "*Table found: **db.cliente***", "*Table found: teste.conta*", "*Table found: teste.movimentacao*", "*Table found: teste.movimentacao_categoria*", "*Table **teste.cliente**' doesn't exist*" - Observe que todas as tabelas estão no pacote `teste`, exceto a de clientes que está no `db`, mas alguma coisa tenta modificá-la como se estivesse em `teste`. Tem certeza que você não tem duas classes chamadas `Cliente`? Ou então, que já teve antes e o projeto não foi adequadamente limpo?

Comment: Alterei algumas coisas como pacotes para deixar mais organizado. O problema só acontece se uso mysql. Com o postgre não acontece esse erro. Não entendo o porquê. Será que errei ou falta algo no persinstence.xml?

Comment: O log está com as alterações também.

Comment: Achei o problema! Esse db.cliente que está no log é outra database que tenho e que nela tem a table cliente. Excluí essa database db e assim foi criada a table cliente na database teste. Ainda não sei o porquê, já que estão em databases diferentes. :(